# Update using Nested Queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'lot_login_tracking' with columns:
**lot_i_login_id** is primary key & auto inc

```
lot_i_login_id        lot_i_user_id lot_d_login_stamp       lot_d_logout_stamp
1                     1296          2013-07-11 09:18:32     NULL
2                     1296          2013-07-11 09:55:38     NULL
3                     1296          2013-07-11 09:57:38     NULL
```

I'm Executing follow query when user log out:

```
UPDATE lot_login_tracking SET lot_d_logout_stamp = "2013-07-11 19:28:21" 
WHERE lot_i_login_id = ( SELECT max(lot_i_login_id) 
                         FROM lot_login_tracking WHERE lot_i_user_id = 1296)
```

And getting an error:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table
>   'lot_login_tracking' for update in FROM clause.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative is to use join,

```
UPDATE  lot_login_tracking a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  max(lot_i_login_id) m
            FROM    lot_login_tracking 
            WHERE   lot_i_user_id = 1296
        ) b ON a.lot_i_login_id = b.m
SET     a.lot_d_logout_stamp = '2013-07-11 19:28:21'
```